# I'm Wandering About - A Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> I'm wandering about.
>   There's always blue overhead.
>   The dear ones frolic,
>   And few words are said.
>
> Or, maybe I'm a place.
>   A creepy lake forked,
>   And I'm locked in its shadow,
>   My key worn and warped.
>
> No, I am here -
>   Embodied by this very text.
>   Think about what I'm doing,
>   And why you're so perplexed.

**What am I?**

Hint (edited):

> The first stanza references the unofficial anthem of the American West.

Comment: Easy to read that title as "I'm Wondering About A Riddle" :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is simply:

> **Buffalo**

Explanation:

> The 3 stanzas are about 3 common meanings of the word Buffalo. The first is about the animal, which as the OP hinted is the animal roaming about in the song Home on the Range. The second is about the city Buffalo in NY, and the hints are the creepy lake (Erie) and '**key worn**' being warped (**New York**). And the third is about the slang word Buffalo, which means to deceive or confuse.

Comment: That's exactly it!

Answer (score 3):

It could be:

> The Buffalo Snowstorm of 2014

because:

> In "Home on the Range" the buffalo roam i.e. wander and Buffalo is located on Lake Erie and near the fork of the Niagara River. Blizzards 'obscure' sightlines, etc. and the snow 'covered' parts of Buffalo for eight months.

Comment: You're very close indeed. The last stanza is not describing a particular event...

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Nimbus

I'm wandering about.
There's always blue overhead.
The dear ones frolic,
And few words are said.

> Flying Nimbus from Dragon ball series. Blue sky is overhead. Dear ones like Goku is frolic.and he just call nimbus(few word(s)) and it will come.

Or, maybe I'm a place.
A creepy lake forked,
And I'm locked in its shadow,
My key worn and warped.

> Nimbus Dam.a place.when the dam opens forked water comes out, normally water is locked and shadowed by dam walls.

No, I am here -
Embodied by this very text.
Think about what I'm doing,
And why you're so perplexed.

> Nimbus(cipher). You're here in the internet embodied(encrypted). But when I try to think about your working process, I am so perplexed.

Comment: Though, for your first answer I'd be more apt to think of the cloud..

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Niagara Falls/Waterfalls

because:

> the blue overhead could be a reference to water falling. Niagara is a fork of lake Eerie and it is located outside of Lockport, NY. The last stanza seems to Waterfall downwards visually.

Comment: Sorry, no. You're headed in the right direction with the second stanza, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> A cloud

First stanza

> It's always a clear sky above the clouds (blue, although a very dark blue at night)
>  "Dear ones" can be dead relatives in heaven
>  Clouds glide softly/quietly.  They're one of the go-tos for comparison for quiet.

Second stanza

> The reflection of a cloud shows up in a lake, the surface of the lake warps the image of the cloud (the key).

Third Stanza

> You're "clouding" the issue, hence embodied by this very text, and the cloudiness is perplexing

Comment: You're on the right track for stanza 3, but this is not the intended answer

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer be

> Fog?

Apparently @Jesse 's third stanza is mostly correct, and @zfrisch 's second is mostly correct and

> Fog is related so both eerieness and cloudieness

For the first stanza

> The fog blocks out the blue sky above it. The dear ones frolicing could be the water molecules moving in the fog, and the few words are said part could be about the bad mood and eerieness of fog.

I will make my explanation more detailed in a later edit.